# Непонятная проблема с приложением android.

Tags: android, android-threads

У меня есть проект приложения над которым я работаю довольно продолжительный период. Сам проект занимает 200мб дискового пространства. Но при установке приложения ставится апк который весит намного меньше. До сегодня все было круто, в том плане что тестирование происходило прекрасно и все работало более-менее быстро. Использую эмулятор GenyMotion на 10 винде. 
Но что-то произошло и я не могу найти причину проблемы. Сейчас приложение тупит очень сильно, и в логах такая строка:

```
Skipped 46 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
Skipped 60 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

если я правильно понял - в главном потоке приложения делается очень много работы. Но почему ранmit все работало более-менее гладко??? Я попробовал переустановить эмулятор, пробовал переустановить устройства на эмуляторе, но ничего не изменилось. Я не могу понять что вообще происходит и как решить эту проблему.

Comment: когда-то были в логах у меня такие строки, но приложение не лагало. Разбирался - вроде ничего критичного. Скорее всего, проблема ваших лагов в другом: в чем - надо мерить

Comment: чем мерить? профайлером? я просто с таким первый раз столкнулся и не знаю что делать)) буду рад если поможете)

Comment: почитайте здесь: https://habr.com/post/279979/ - когда-то написал статью на Хабр (как раз про упомянутое мной приложение). Там есть ссылки где и как мерить (посмотрите видеоуроки, если ссылки на них еще живые :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

За сутки я уже перепробовал все что угодно: удалял GenyMotion, ставил другой эмулятор. Но ничего не менялось. Программа лагала очень жестко и я не знал как решить эту проблему. Дальше я нашел способ который вроде решил мою проблему. В манифесте нужно добавить строку:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

и мне это вроде как помогло. Но я так же полностью переустановил эмулятор - не только саму программу но и виртуальную машину. Но я не уверен что переустановка эмулятора - решение данной проблемы. Может кому-то поможет данный вариант решения.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, я так предполагаю, что у вас во всем приложении очень много операций делается в главном потоке. Для того, чтобы решить данную проблему вам нужно вынести большинство ваших действий в приложении в новые потоки. Тем самым вы оптимизирует работу.

Создание нового потока(не можем обращаться к ui) :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
public void run() {
  //do time consuming operations
  });
} }).start();
```

Comment: не очень понял если честно, о каких потоках вообще идет речь и как вынести в поток что-то?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko у вас в приложении выполняются какие-то очень тяжелые операции. Например обращение к БД или что-то подобное.
Эти операции нужно вынести в отдельный поток, как создать поток написал выше.

Comment: проблема в том что осуществляется запрос к серверу и все, ничего супер тяжелого нету, и то что сейчас происходит очень странно

Comment: можно просто профайлером пройтись и посмотреть, что там на самом деле

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko есть еще очень большая вероятность что очень медленный эмулятор и из-за этого так лагает. Проверьте частоту кадров

Comment: @MartinezToni, а как это проверить? я просто уже его переустановил, и я не могу понять почему так тупит только сейчас? ведь раньше было все красиво и гладко. На телефоне все гуд

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko должно в логах быть следующее сообщение:
“Skipped n frames. Too much work on main thread”

Comment: @MartinezToni, да есть такое. но я не понял что это

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko это частота смены кадров. Если их меньше 100, то это проблемы с эмулятором. Если больше 300 то это проблемы с кодом .

Comment: @MartinezToni, намного меньше, максимум 60 вроде, до 100 вообще не доходит.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko ну значит с эмулятором проблемы. Слишком медленный и слабый. Попробуйте запустить на реальном девайсе.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87185/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-martinez-toni).